# Jquery clicking dynamic created elements with buttons and on doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are a lot of answered questions here, but I think this is a more specific problem.

I populate a div with dynamically generated products. Each product has an input field with a plus and min button to adjust the amount inside the input.

Whatever I try I can't get it to work. I know I have to use `on` to click dynamic elements.

My HTML

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="custom-products" data-getnew="popular-products"></div> 
</div>
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="custom-products" data-getnew="newest-products"></div> 
</div>
```

My Jquery

```
function customProducts(url, container){
   $.get(url + '?format=json', function(e){
        var productsHtml = [];
            $.each(e.products, function(index, product) {

              var productHtml = '<div class="col col-25 m-50 t-25 item-grid"><div class="item quick-view-item  clearfix" data-handle="'+product.url+'" data-vid="'+product.vid+'">
              .......
              .......
              productHtml = productHtml + '<div class="to-cart"><form action="/cart/add/'+product.vid+'" id="product_configure_form_'+product.id+'" method="post"><div class="custom-quantity-input"><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"><div class="item-quantity-btns"><div class="up quantity-btn quantity-input-up"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div><div class="down quantity-btn quantity-input-down"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div></div></div><button type="submit" class="item-add-btn-cart btn btn-custom-1 with-qty redirect" title=""></button></form></div> </div> </div> </div> </div>';
             productsHtml.push(productHtml);
            });
            productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');
        $(container).html(productsHtml);
    })
}
```

And then run it like this:

```
$(function(){

$('.carousel-wrapper .custom-products').each(function(){
  var url = $(this).data('getnew')
  var container = $(this)
    customProducts(url, container)
});
```

To click the plus/min buttons

```
$('.carousel-wrapper .custom-products').each(function(){
   $('.item-grid').on('click', '.up', function (){ 
     console.log($(this))
     alert('test')
   });
   $('.item-grid').on('click', '.down', function (){ 
     console.log($(this))
     alert('test')
   });
 });
 .....
```

Why does this not work? Console and alert don't show anything. To my understanding you have a static container with the dynamic items and then you select the button with `.on`. What's wrong with that?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to trigger the event on the document when elements are created dinammically.

`$(document).on('.item-grid .down', 'click', function (){`

Comment: Exactly.Events for DOM elements created after script load (Dynamically created elements) will  not be triggered.So you have to use event on the document ,which will look for the entire document for the particular element.

Comment: @Roy: Yes exactly what I thought. But that doesn't work :( Can it be that the plus/min buttons are `display:none` on first. And when you hover the input then those buttons will become visible?!?!

Comment: @Meules are you sure that exists the class `.down` inside `.item-grid`?

Comment: @Roy: Yes absolutely sure!! You can see it in the html that is created in the function.

Comment: @Meules Check if the `$('.carousel-wrapper .custom-products').each(function(){`is working... console.log something inside to see if works.